# When Calculating the Inner Product, Why Do We (Seemingly) Always Integrate From $0$ to $1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inner-products

I've always seen the inner product $\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle$ written as

$$\langle f(x), g(x)\rangle = \int_0^1 f(x)g(x)w(x) \ dx$$

where $w(x)$ is a weight function.

But why do we always integrate from $0$ to $1$? And why not other values?

If we do integrate over other values, why is integrating over the domain from $0$ to $1$ so common?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: just a suspect: $f, g$ have domains $[0, 1]$.

Comment: It isn't always.  For example in the space $L_2$ on the real line the inner product is $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)g(x)dx$ for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in the space.

Comment: I added an extra question: If we do integrate over other values, why is integrating over the domain from $0$ to $1$ so common?

Comment: You can harmlessly change variables to make your interval be either $[0,1]$ (if it is bounded), $[0,\infty)$ (if it is semi-infinite) or $(-\infty,\infty)$. "Harmlessly" means that the absolute value of the derivative of your change of variable mapping is in some interval $[c,d]$, $0<c<d<\infty$. This may be inconvenient sometimes, though; for example, the Legendre polynomials are usually defined on $[-1,1]$.

Comment: @Ian Interesting. Would you please give an example/demonstration?

Comment: There's not a lot to it: $\int_a^b f(x) dx = (b-a) \int_0^1 f(a+(b-a)x) dx$.

Comment: In some contexts, $[-\pi,\pi]$ is more convenient.  See e.g. [these notes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/presentation/89e4/d505bb2a402fbc1ce79665b7ae3909d71c79.pdf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a function of the material. The eigenfunctions are typically just orthogonal between $a$ and $b$ i.e.

$$ \int_{a}^{b} \phi_{n}(x)\phi_{m}(x) \sigma(x) dx =0  , \lambda_{n} \neq \lambda_{m} $$

typically in PDEs you start off with $0$ to $L$  i.e 
$$ \int_{0}^{L} \phi_{n}(x) \phi_{m}(x) \sigma(x) dx  $$
and $\sigma(x) =1$ , $ \lambda_{n} = \left( \frac{n \pi }{L} \right)^{2} $ then $  \phi_{n}(x) = \sin(\frac{ n \pi x}{L})$ for instance

when we have 
$$ \frac{d^{2}\phi}{dx^{2}} + \lambda \phi =0  \\ \phi(0) = 0 \\ \phi(L) = 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following two questions, in order:

- What is the simplest number you can think of, especially one you might use as a starting point?
- What is the next simplest number you can think of, especially one you might use as an ending point?

I posit that by far the most common answers to these questions are $0$ and $1$ respectively. Therefore, this is the example that gets used the most.

Taking $0 \to 1$ as your "reference" path has an additional advantage in that if you want to convert to another path $a \to b$, it's extremely easy to recreate the affine formula for it:

$$ t \mapsto a (1-t) + b t $$